# Cohomology ring of grassmannian and Pieri rule

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, homology-cohomology, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

I am learning Schubert variety and I came across a problem to understand a particular detail (I asked the same question on mathoverflow : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397999/cohomology-ring-of-grassmannian-and-pieri-rule):

Let $X=OG(n,2n+1)$, where $OG(n,2n+1)$ denotes the variety of $n$-dimensional isotropic subspaces of a vector space $\mathbb{C}^{2n+1}$ with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form.

According to Theorem 2.2 a) (Page 17, Anders Skovsted Buch, Andrew Kresch, Harry Tamvakis, Quantum Pieri rules for isotropic grassmannians, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4966.pdf), the cohomology ring of X is given by
$$ H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}[\tau_{1},\ldots, \tau_{n}]/I,$$

where $I$ is the ideal generated by
$$ \tau_{r}^{2}-2\tau_{r+1}\tau_{r-1}+2\tau_{r+2}\tau_{r-2}+\cdots +(-1)^{r}\tau_{2r}$$
for $1\leq r\leq n$.

In particular, if $n=4$, then the ideal $I$ is generated by the following four elements

$$
\tau_{1}^{2}-\tau_{2},\quad \tau_{2}^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}+\tau_{4}, \quad \tau_{3}^{2}-2\tau_{4}\tau_{2},\quad \tau_{4}^{2}.\tag{*}\label{*}$$
But if I apply Pieri rule for X (Theorem 2.1, Page 16, Anders Skovsted Buch, Andrew Kresch, Harry Tamvakis, Quantum Pieri rules for isotropic grassmannians, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4966.pdf) to $\tau_{2}\cdot \tau_{2}$, I get the following relation

$$\tau_{2}^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}-\tau_{4} \tag{**}\label{**}$$

Therefore, combining (\ref{*}) and (\ref{**}), I get $2\tau_{4}=0$ in $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. I seems that some computation is wrong, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: It is only over $\mathbb{Z}$ not a field so you can't go from $2\tau_4=0$ to $\tau_4=0$

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited the statement.

Comment: It seems that at the beginning of Section 2 the authors assume that $k>0$. i am not sure why though/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But I guess that theorems hold for $k=0$ (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Also asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397999/cohomology-ring-of-grassmannian-and-pieri-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $\tau_2^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}-\tau_{4}$ (obtained by Pieri rule) is incorrect. It should be
$$\tau_2^{2}-2\tau_{3,1}-\tau_{4},$$
so there is no problem for such computations.